# Two ListFragment triggered by two Button

Tags: android, android-button, android-listfragment

This batch of code works only for the first Button press, regardless of which Button I click, the designated area will show a ListFragment populated with correct values, just as desired. But when I click the alternate Button it will not replace the fragment_container, it just crashes.

```
public void selectTamFragment(View view){
    TamInputListFragment lstfragment=(TamInputListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("lstfragment");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You pressed tamButton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(lstfragment==null){
            lstfragment=new TamInputListFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transact.add(R.id.fragment_container, lstfragment, "lstfragment");
            transact.commit();
    }

}
public void selectVerbFragment(View view){
    VerbInputListFragment lstfragment=(VerbInputListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("lstfragment");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You pressed verbButton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(lstfragment==null){
        lstfragment=new VerbInputListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transact.add(R.id.fragment_container, lstfragment, "lstfragment");
        transact.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share the crash log, with out knowing much information my guess is you are using same tag names for both the fragments, so try using different tag names for each (lstfragment_1 & lstfragment_2)

```
public void selectTamFragment(View view){
TamInputListFragment lstfragment=(TamInputListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("lstfragment_1");

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You pressed tamButton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(lstfragment==null){
        lstfragment=new TamInputListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transact.add(R.id.fragment_container, lstfragment, "lstfragment_1");
        transact.commit();
}
  }

public void selectVerbFragment(View view){
VerbInputListFragment lstfragment=(VerbInputListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("lstfragment_2");

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You pressed verbButton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

if(lstfragment==null){
    lstfragment=new VerbInputListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transact.add(R.id.fragment_container, lstfragment, "lstfragment_2");
    transact.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get the crash log, as it loads fine on my android studio, and only crashes when the 2nd button gets pressed. But you're code did work but with only one problem, it didn't "replace" the fragment, it just put the fragment over the TOP of the previous one, any ideas?

Comment: I added "replace" instead of add and its working fine now :) Thank you so much.